# Why it's so slow to use `rails new`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The version is:

```
bash-3.2$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.9
```

And my ruby is the built-in ruby on MacOSX:

```
bash-3.2$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
bash-3.2$ which ruby 
/usr/bin/ruby
```

My problem is that  in the last step of `rails new` ( `run  bundle install`), it seems that rails need to connect the internet to download some packages. And usually I need 5 minutes just wait for `rails` to create any project using `rails new`.

I was wondering whether somethings is not configured well for rails on my computer.

Another strange thing is that after I finished `rails new PROJECT_NAME`, it shows:

```
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6)
Using uglifier (1.3.0) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

It seems that `sqlite3` has already been installed, however, when I try:

```
bash-3.2$ bundle show sqlite3
 Could not locate Gemfile
```

It still complains that `sqlite3`is not installed. Maybe that's the reason that `rails new` is slow (Even `sqlite3` has been installed once. It still needs to download the bundle)

Before `bundle install`, rails asks for my system password:

```
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system
```

But I'm still not sure whether these packages have been installed into system, as `bundle show sqlite3` failed.

Does anyone have ideas about why `rails new` is so slow on my computer? Thanks!

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure as I'm using the built-in Ruby on MacOS

Comment: install ruby 1.9.x version, your Ruby version is old.

Comment: Do you `cd` into your newly created Rails app directory before typing `bundle show`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to use [RVM](http://rvm.io). It is similar to rbenv. I personally use RVM. I don't and would not recommend using the gemsets. Bundler does the separation of gem versions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check what is up with your `bundle install` i.e. the last step in the rails new sequence. Run this instead:

> `rails new appname -B`

The `-B` flag tells rails to "skip bundle" ([reference](https://gist.github.com/brianpetro/2c59916af11c65aac155)). Then go into the app folder to run:

> `bundle install --verbose`

Check for potential errors in the output.

2. Using different bundler versions can give you different results. So try [other versions](https://rubygems.org/gems/bundler/versions).

> `gem uninstall bundler -v your-version-number`
>
> `gem install bundler -v new-version-number`

3. In 2016, we got bundler v1.12.x which is causing some users to experience [slow bundle install issues](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4478#issuecomment-219263764). In this case, using 1.11.2 is the faster option until they fix it.